# How to customize the solution of multichoice question in exam documentclass?

Tags: exam

[image: I want to my document was displayed like this image]

```
\documentclass[cancelspace,10pt]{exam}
\usepackage{multicol}
%**********************************************************  End of Listing Setting
\usepackage[explicit]{titlesec}
\usepackage[dotinlabels]{titletoc}
\usepackage{pifont}
\usepackage{times,color}
\usepackage{tikz}
\usepackage{circuitikz}
\usepackage{enumerate}

\usepackage{xepersian}
% *********************************************************** Document Font
\settextfont[Scale=1.2]{B Nazanin}
%*******************************************
\renewcommand*\questionlabel{\color{blue}\thequestion-}
\renewcommand*\thechoice{\arabic{choice}} 
\renewcommand*\choicelabel{\thechoice)}
%*******************************answer
\renewcommand{\solutiontitle}{\noindent\textbf{solution:}\par\noindent}
\shadedsolutions
\definecolor{SolutionColor}{rgb}{0.8,0.9,1}
\printanswers
% *********************************************************** begin Doc
%\DefaultMathsDigits
\begin{document}
% ----------------------------------------------------------------
%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%end-title
\begin{persian}
\begin{questions}
% *********************************************************** Start Doc

\begin{latin}
%#############################################################################
% *********************************************************** Start     QUESTION #1
\question
She's not very .............. in the way she treats her children;they may be punished today for somthing they were rewarded for yesterday!
% *********************************************************** Choices
\begin{multicols}{4}
\begin{choices}
        %****************************************************************************     Choice 1
    \choice
    a
    %****************************************************************************     Choice 2
    \choice
           b
    %****************************************************************************     Choice 3
    \choice
    c
    %****************************************************************************     Choice 4
    \choice
    d
\end{choices}
\end{multicols}
  \begin{solutionorbox}[2in]

a

\end{solutionorbox}
% *********************************************************** End QUESTION #1


\end{latin}
\end{questions}
\end{persian}
\end{document}
```

Comment: Sorry, when editing your post, I see `I want to my document was displayed like this image`. Is it your real question?

Comment: @Asis Pattisahusiwa:Thanks for your attention.I want to change the second word of the sentence[The first option is correct],like second in [The second option is correct],but the effect of the sentence isn't matter.

Comment: Please make clear your question above.

Comment: @ Asis Pattisahusiwa.Thanks.sure.I don't want to write this sentence[The first option is correct] completely in all of my question,just I like to have a command and I just write first or second or third or forth words,and i don't want to write complete sentences like this[the first option is correct],I want to renewcommand \begin{solutionorbox}[2in] to \begin{solutionorbox}[2in]{first} to show this sentence [the first option is correct] in solution environment.

Comment: Please see my answer below.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I think you can use this code to modify yours.

```
\documentclass{exam}

\usepackage{xcolor}
\usepackage{ifthen}

\shadedsolutions
\definecolor{SolutionColor}{rgb}{0.8,0.9,1}
\printanswers

\newcommand{\answer}{unknown}

\newcommand{\correct}[1]
{
    \ifthenelse{\equal{#1}{a}}{\renewcommand{\answer}{The first }}{}
    \ifthenelse{\equal{#1}{b}}{\renewcommand{\answer}{The second }}{}
    \ifthenelse{\equal{#1}{c}}{\renewcommand{\answer}{The third }}{}
    \ifthenelse{\equal{#1}{d}}{\renewcommand{\answer}{The fourth }}{}

    \renewcommand{\solutiontitle}{\noindent \textbf{Solution:} \answer option is correct.\par\noindent}

    \begin{solutionorbox}[2in]
        #1 
    \end{solutionorbox}
}

\begin{document}

\correct{a}

\correct{b}

\correct{c}

\correct{d}

\end{document}
```

Will display

[image]

> #### Edit
>
> In edited `\correct` command, you need to type in format `\correct{option}{the answer}` with `option` MUST in the number format. In your example then the option is `1`, `2`, `3`, or `4`.
>
> ```
> \documentclass{exam}
>
> \usepackage{xcolor}
> \usepackage{ifthen}
>
> \usepackage{fmtcount}
>
> \shadedsolutions
> \definecolor{SolutionColor}{rgb}{0.8,0.9,1}
> \printanswers
>
> \newcommand{\correct}[2]
> { 
>     \renewcommand{\solutiontitle}{\noindent \textbf{Solution:} The \textcolor{red}{\ordinalstringnum{#1}} option is correct.\par\noindent}
>
>     \begin{solutionorbox}[2in]
>         \textcolor{red}{#2}
>     \end{solutionorbox}
> }
>
> \begin{document}
>
> \correct{1}{c}
>
> \correct{2}{d}
>
> \correct{1}{You should choose this as your answer}
>
> \correct{2}{I think this is the right answer}
>
> \end{document}
> ```
>
> [image]
>
> > Second edited:
> >
> > Please replace `\newcommand{\correct}[2]` in the code above with this one.
> >
> > ```
> > \newcommand{\answer}{unknown}
> >
> > \newcommand{\correct}[2]
> > {    
> >
> >    \ifthenelse{\equal{#1}{1}}{\renewcommand{\answer}{pertama }}{}
> >    \ifthenelse{\equal{#1}{2}}{\renewcommand{\answer}{kedua }}{}
> >    \ifthenelse{\equal{#1}{3}}{\renewcommand{\answer}{ketiga }}{}
> >    \ifthenelse{\equal{#1}{4}}{\renewcommand{\answer}{keempat }}{}
> >
> >
> >    \renewcommand{\solutiontitle}{\noindent \textbf{Solution:} The \answer option is correct.\par\noindent}
> >
> >    \begin{solutionorbox}[2in]
> >        #2
> >    \end{solutionorbox}
> > }
> > ```
> >
> > If you need to use persian language, just replace `pertama`, `kedua`, `ketiga`, and `keempat` with yours.

Comment: @ Asis Pattisahusiwa.Thank you for your answer,but a or b or c or d  are not fixed,in the other words instead of a it can be proportional ,or instead of b it can be consistent and so...I just example a,b,c,d...

Comment: Please see edited answer.

Comment: @Gonzalo Medina.Thank you very much...your answer is informative  and very useful for me.

Comment: @ Asis Pattisahusiwa.Thank you for your answer.my problem was solved by your code :),but I have new question about your code,how can I use arabaicnumber instead of \ordinalstringnum in persian documents?in persian first equal to اول  or second equal to دوم

Comment: You can take a look on fmtcount package documentation http://www.ctan.org/pkg/fmtcount to see what alternative command that suitable for your problem instead \ordinalstringnum. If you couldn't found any, you can see in the previous code about defined some constants with ifthenelse

Comment: Please see my last edited answer above.

Comment: @ Asis Pattisahusiwa.Thank you very much:).my problem was solved completely by your answers.good luck...

Comment: @ Gonzalo Medina.Thank you,my problem was solved completely

Comment: let us [continue this discussion in chat](http://chat.stackexchange.com/rooms/14432/discussion-between-user50054-and-asis-pattisahusiwa)

Answer (score 1):

Here's one possible solution. I defined a `\CorrectSolution` command with an optional argument that will be passed to the optional argument of `solutionorbox`:

```
\CorrectSolution[2in]
```

and a `\coreectoption` command to be used inside the `choices` environment to select the correct answer:

```
\begin{choices}
    \correctoption{a}
    \choice b
    \choice c
    \choice d
\end{choices}
```

then `\CorrectSolution` will automatically grab the value of the right answer and convert it to its associated ordinal string with the help of the `fmtcount` package.

The code:

```
\documentclass[cancelspace,10pt]{exam}
\usepackage{multicol}
\usepackage{fmtcount}
\usepackage{color}

\renewcommand*\questionlabel{\color{blue}\thequestion-}
\renewcommand*\thechoice{\arabic{choice}} 
\renewcommand*\choicelabel{\thechoice)}

%*******************************answer
\renewcommand{\solutiontitle}{\noindent\textbf{solution:}\par\noindent}
\shadedsolutions
\definecolor{SolutionColor}{rgb}{0.8,0.9,1}

\newcounter{tmp}
\newcommand\correctoption[1]{\gdef\Correctoption{#1}\choice#1\setcounter{tmp}{\value{choice}}}
\newcommand\CorrectSolution[1][-1t]{%
  \begin{solutionorbox}[#1]
    The  \ordinalstring{tmp} option is correct.\par\Correctoption  
  \end{solutionorbox}%
}

\printanswers

\begin{document}

\begin{questions}
\question
She's not very .............. in the way she treats her children;they may be punished today for somthing they were rewarded for yesterday!
\begin{multicols}{4}
\begin{choices}
    \correctoption{a}
    \choice b
    \choice c
    \choice d
\end{choices}
\end{multicols}
\CorrectSolution[2in]

\question
What is the answer to the ultimate question of life, the universe, and everything?\begin{multicols}{4}
\begin{choices}
    \choice 15
    \choice 23
    \choice $\pi$
    \correctoption{42}
    \choice 31
\end{choices}
\end{multicols}
\CorrectSolution[2in]

\end{questions}

\end{document}
```

[image]

Since my system doesn't have the `B Nazanin` font, I commented out that line. I also removed packages and settings that were not relevant to the answer.

Comment: Thank you Mr. @Gonzalo Medina for your answer.your answer is very useful for me but I liked to see the correct choice for example [a]below the sentence[The first option is correct].

Comment: @user50054 Please see my updated answer.